# Borrowing at a gain (negative rates on bank mortgages, Bloomberg news)

Tags: credit

I have been very curious when I first read the Bloomberg news attached [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/bundesbank-open-possibility-negative-rate-160205220.html) that the Bundesbank considers such mortgages with negative rates

> conceivable and would not intervene against them

What do you think when it comes to borrowers’ reaction and impact on the broader loan environment in Europe? What’s your assessment?

To improve clarity, I attach the first few lines of the article as follows

> Germany’s central bank, known for its dry approach to matters of money, has some good news for real-estate buyers: negative-rate mortgages are just fine.
>   The Bundesbank considers such loans conceivable and would not intervene against them.

I look forward to hearing your smart opinions on the point.